# Xcode fails to upload binary

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I am getting the following warning when I try to upload a binary to iTunes Connect. It happens on Xcode 7.1.1 and Application Loader the same way.

[image]

Any suggestions on how to get this warning solved? I can't really find this AppDelegate.o that iTunes claims to be bundled with the app.

info.plist:

[image]

Comment: Have you reviewed the Bundle Programming Guide as suggested in the warning?

Comment: Yes I did, I understand that is invalid I just wanted to know how to remove it from there since I don't recall doing anything that could generate this warning other than recently updating to 7.1.1

Comment: I recommend posting your INFO PLIST file, so that we can better understand your bundle settings. Moreover, there may also be an issue with your Xcode target. It's hard to know without knowing more about project configuration and the INFO PLIST.  Another option would be to post this issue in the Apple Xcode developer forum.

Comment: The only thing I manually edited was the "Allow arbitrary loads" because of that HTTP issue with iOS 9.

Comment: I never had such an issue and one thing that I am doing differently from my previous project is that I am using CocoaPods. Could this be related somehow?

Comment: Yes, CocoaPods edits your project file. You must open your project using the workspace file. Otherwise, it will not link properly. Look for the file named `<project>.xcworkspace` and open it. Then try to recompile and link.

Comment: Yes I am aware of this step: opening from the xcworkspace file. I'll do it again just to double check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96199/discussion-between-johnnieb-and-cj-coimbra).